# How Function overloading saves memory

Tags: c#, c++, oop, c#-4.0

How does function overloading saves memory ?

What is difference between the following two types of functions definitions, and which one should be used ?

1)

```
ADD(a,b)
ADD(a,b,c)
ADD(a,b,c,d)
```

2)

```
AddTwoNumbers(a,b)
AddThreeNumbers(a,b,c)
AddFourNumbers(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: From the answers you're getting, everyone seems to be assuming that all three functions are doing the one ADD function, but with varying number of arguments. But that's not necessarily the case. Unlikely though it seems, the three functions, however named, might be doing three distinct jobs.  In which case, the latter coding style would make more sense. If they're doing basically the same thing, then the former is better.  But as everyone has already mentioned, it's more a coding style and shouldn't have a performance difference.

Answer (score 9):

> How Function overloading saves memory.

At runtime, it doesn't. **Overloading is resolved at compile time**, so it has no impact on performance.

> What is difference between the following two types of functions
>   definitions,

They are overloaded functions, taking multiple parameters, which IMO would be more readable

> which one should be used ?

Overloading would be more readable, (You may also see [Member Overloading - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029.aspx)) but If you are using C# 4.0 or higher then you can use [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) as well.

Define it like:

```
public int ADD(int a, int b, int c = 0, int d = 0)
{
    //..... your code
    return result;
}
```

Call it like:

```
ADD(2, 3);
ADD(2, 3, 4);
ADD(2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Answer (score 4):

Function overloading does not save memory.

Answer (score 3):

When we write Overloaded method ,It dont not save any space and not improves performance. It is only used for better readabilty and implementing polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the difference is the name ;-).
About which one should you use... the long names use a few more bytes of memory, but that should be negligible in any system that can run C#-4, so just use what you like best.

I personally would use:

```
Add(a,b);
Add(a,b,c);
Add(a,b,c,d);
```

The `XXXNumbers` is redundant with the parameter list, so it provides nothing.

And the all-uppercase version is just ugly.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, these are just the function calls and not their prototypes/definitions

1)

```
ADD(a,b)
ADD(a,b,c)
ADD(a,b,c,d)
```

These will act as overloaded functions

2)

```
AddTwoNumbers(a,b)
AddThreeNumbers(a,b,c)
AddFourNumbers(a,b,c,d)
```

These three will act like three different functions(not overloaded).

Overloaded functions have same function name with varying number of parameters.
Internally 'name mangling' takes place and the compiler has to create three different functions. It doesn't help much with respect to saving memory, but improves readability

Answer (score 0):

Function overloading never saves space, internally compiler creates two different version of function and depending upon the call it will call different version of functions.

Function overloading makes your code more readable.

```
1)

ADD(a,b)
ADD(a,b,c)
ADD(a,b,c,d)

2)

AddTwoNumbers(a,b)
AddThreeNumbers(a,b,c)
AddFourNumbers(a,b,c,d)
```

This is same like a overloading , but above code is more readable.